# Can't call universal link nuxt 2

Tags: nuxt.js, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to call the universal link on iOS. But nuxt 2 is handling 404 and redirecting to error.vue page. apple-app-site-association file configured on the web.

If there is an app installed then it should redirect to my app. If not redirect to web path.

Web link example
https://www.example.com/home/detail/2568

Deeplink example:
myapp://home/detail/2568